# Horizontally center two TextView with RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-relativelayout

**Problem:**

Im trying to horizontally center these two TextView, but can't seem to find a solution.
[image]

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/have_account_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/register_btn"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Already have an account? "
    android:textColor="@color/black" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/login_now_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textFontWeight="700"
    android:textColor="@color/main_blue"
    android:layout_below="@+id/register_btn"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/have_account_tv"
    android:text="Log in now" />
```

**Solution**

I've solved this using LinearLayout wrapping both TextView, and then set centerHorizontal="true".

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_btn">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/havent_register_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Haven't Registered? "
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_now_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textFontWeight="700"
        android:textColor="@color/main_blue"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/havent_register_tv"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/havent_register_tv"
        android:text="Register Here"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding following attribute to the TextView XMLs

```xml
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Comment: Tried. Applying centerHorizontal=true to either one will cause one text view to be centered horizontally while pushing the other to the side. Applying to both also doesn't work.

Comment: @AhChing11 I misunderstood your question. Do you want these views side by side? Because they both have ` android:layout_below="@+id/register_btn"` in them. So both of them can't be centered horizontally else they will overlap each other

Comment: owh, then what should i do?

Comment: There are many options here, you can just have a single `TextView` and then use spans to change the color of the text in between. Or you can add a `LinearLayout` in between and use weights system to divide them 50/50. Even better is you go for `ConstraintLayout`, it is similar to `RelativeLayout` but lot more powerful. 

@AhChing11

Comment: Ahh okay, I think I will just go for using LinearLayout, thank you.